# How to change size of collider attached to UI Image in unity

Tags: unity, rigidbody

I have a circle image which has a Cicle collider 2D and Rigidbody 2D attached to it and its size (width and height) is constantly increasing in script like this:

```
rt = circle.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
float width = rt.rect.width + increment;
float height = rt.rect.height + increment;
rt.sizeDelta = new Vector2 (width, height);
```

The collider doesn't change size with UI Image as it expands...what should i do in order to make the collider change size as UI Image changes size.

Comment: You may not need colliders in a UI object. What are you trying to achieve from the collider?

Comment: I want the circular UI image to trigger an event once it hits the walls.

Comment: Previously i was using sprites and i think with sprites colliders change size by itself as the sprite changes size. But i was having problem with increasing the size of sprite pixel by pixel because i am a beginner.

Comment: Is wall a 3D object with 3D collider?

Comment: No the game is 2D... walls have box collider 2d

Answer (score 1):

Create `private CircleCollider2D _yourImageCollider;`.

Assign it on awake, so you don't need to lose performance for getting it every time.

```
private void Awake()
{ 
    this._yourImageCollider = GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>(); 
}
```

When you increase / decrease width and height - change colliders radius `this._yourImageCollider.radius += increment * 0.5f;`.

Or you can set radius of the collider to match exactly the size of an image plus the offset if it's necessary.

```
private float _colliderRadiusOffset = 0.4f;
.
. Code
.
    this._yourImageCollider.radius = rt.rect.width + this._colliderRadiusOffset;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update(){
     if(rt.sizeDelta.x > oldSizeX + accuracy){ //Compare UI circle X size to its old size + accuracy offser
          if(rt.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>() != null) //If it actually has a circle collider
             Destroy(rt.GetComponent<CircleCollider2D>()); //Remove it
             rt.AddComponent<CircleCollider2D>(); //The add a new one to fit the current size
             oldSizeX = rt.sizeDelta.x; //Reset the old size, and wait for it to expand beyond the accuracy offset
     }
  }
```

The lower the accuracy, the slower your game will be, try to update the new collider once every 0.5 units or so, but it's your choice.

Also, this only works if the circle is expanding like you explained in your example.